# Why does my instance behave incorrectly?

Tags: python

Why can I set the height but cannot pass a function to `collidetext` during instantiation?

If I check `slum.height`, it is `10` (because I set it as `10` when `slum` was instantiated), but if I call `slum.collisiontext`, it just calls the `somefunction` rather than the function I assigned to `slum` when the instance was created.

I don't get it.

```
class BgImages(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.collidetext=somefunction
        self.height=0

    def collisiontext(self,**kwargs):
        return self.collidetext()

class MainCharacter(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainCharacter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

    elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            for i in listofwidgets:
                if i.collide_point(self.x,self.top):
                    self.y -=1
                    i.collisiontext()

class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        slum=BgImages(source='slum.png', collidetext=slumnotice, height=10)
        police=BgImages(source='police.png', collidetext=policenotice)
        listofwidgets=[]
        listofwidgets.append(slum)
        listofwidgets.append(police)
```

Comment: Did you notice that you don't use *kwargs* in the *collisiontext* method?

Comment: Those are functions that you pass as one of *kwargs* values. Not trying "to do anything with a dict key" is exactly your mistake.

Comment: Is there anything I can replace 'kwargs' with so that I can pass a function reference?

Comment: What's the `elif keycode[1] == 'up':` part? It isn't syntactically correct. Even if you put the `if` and `elif` at the same level your code doesn't really have much sense because you'd have a `return` that prevents execution of some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your assignment in *__init__* to

```
self.collidetext = kwargs['collidetext']
```

****kwargs** construct in function definition allows you to send any set of named parameters to the function - within the function they will be visible as a dictionary

```
In [64]: def test(**kwargs):
   ....:     print locals()
   ....:     

In [66]: test(advice='learn')
{'kwargs': {'advice': 'learn'}}
```

An alternative will be to define positional function parameter explicitly in the *__init__* declaration - **before kwargs**

```
def __init__(self, collide_func, **kwargs):
    super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.collidetext=collide_func
    self.height=0
```

And if you don't plan to use key-word parameters - or just need positional parameters - you do not need to add the construct at all (in the **__init__** you need ****kwargs** to pass on to parent class)